# New stackoverflow website design(hide left panel)

Tags: layout

Can someone tell me how to get rid of the new panel on the left on the stackoverflow website? It appeared yesterday, and I assume it to be quite irritating. Thanks!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMf9q.jpg

Comment: Indeed, it's width is a fifth of the whole screen. Very annoying

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit profile & settings -> Site settings -> Preferences -> Navigation -> Hide left navigation